# How can i interface ros with FPGA kit?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to control my multi-link arm(it is based on fpga)using ros....Is it possible?how?

Thanks in advance...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72754/how-can-i-interface-ros-with-fpga-kit?/) by [pavanpatel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5686/pavanpatel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you currently communicate with the FPGA? Do you have another computer running ROS that you want to communicate with the FPGA? Or do you want to run ROS itself on the FPGA?

One idea would be to have a PC running ROS, that communicates with the FPGA. Then you write a ROS node on the PC (either in python or C++) that subscribes to some topic to receive commands for the robot, and then sends those commands to the FPGA using whatever protocol it has. And then gets feedback data back from the FPGA and publishes it on another topic.

---

Originally posted by [davr](https://answers.ros.org/users/32029/davr/) with karma: 46 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0